# SQL to get Latest comment date for a post - Discussion Forum

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, aggregate-functions

I am working on a discussion forum website. When you open the forum, a webservice fetches all the active posts.

Title, Count of Comments, Recent Activity (Date of latest comment), Posted By, Status.

I am able to get all of the above data except Recent Activity.

```
SELECT 
  `post`.`id`, 
  `post`.`title`,
  `post`.`description`, 
  `post`.`created`, 
  COUNT(`comment_text`) AS `num_comments`,
  `users`.`name`, 
  `users`.`nick_name`, 
  `users`.`profile_picture` 
FROM `post`
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `post`.`user_id` 
JOIN `posttype` ON `posttype`.`id` = `post`.`post_type_id` 
LEFT JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`post_id` = `post`.`id` 
WHERE `post_type` = 'Discussion'
GROUP BY `post`.`id`
```

How do I modify this SQL to get latest comment date?

The `comment_date` is in `comments` table

Comment: you can use ORDER BY `comments`.`comment_id` DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX(comment_date)` the same way you're using `COUNT(comment_text)` to get the latest date over all the comments in each `GROUP BY post.id` group.

Be careful, you're exploiting the MySQL non-standard extension to `GROUP BY`. In your case, the extension may cause your result set to contain information from the `users` table that you can't predict.  Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html